# Finding Emoji combinations programmatically, is reversing the Spread Operator possible?

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

There are a number of emojis that are not just stand-alone Unicode characters. They are actually a combination of two or more other emojis. e.g.

```js
console.log([...'‍‍‍']); //  + + + 

console.log([...'‍❤️‍‍']); //  + ❤ +  + 

console.log([...'‍']); //  +
```

What I would like to know, is given the constituent parts, is it possible to go the other way and combine emojis so that you can generate the combined symbol? Really the opposite of what the Spread Operator is doing here.

e.g. Is it possible to generate ‍‍‍ from ,,,

I've tried I few different ideas but nothing seems to work - mainly just getting SyntaxErrors.

Comment: Did you try `join` method of the array?

Comment: Yes I had but was missing the glue...not sure why I didn't just `join` on the result `[
  "",
  "\u200d",
  "",
  "\u200d",
  "",
  "\u200d",
  ""
].join('')` works :)

Comment: Or simpler, `["", "", "", ""].join("\u200d")` (if you're not coming from the results of the string iterator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First link in the google https://www.bram.us/2016/08/27/fun-with-javascript-and-emoji/

```
["", "‍", "", "‍", "", "‍", ""].reduce((prev, next) => prev + next)
```

It is really easy to achieve

Comment: Ah! Nice one - I was missing the ZWJ ("\u200d") glue! Not sure how I missed that page -was reading about Unicode not emojis :)

Comment: @Fraser Actually as Xion 14 said, you can just join them, it is much easier

Comment: yes I realised that - it was the ZWJ "glue" that I was missing :)

Comment: You should not use `reduce` without an initial value. And you shouldn't use `reduce` here at all - just use `join`!